# Facebook OG tags and sharing pages with images

Tags: metadata, facebook-sharer, facebook-opengraph

I have been struggling with this for many hours now and have not gotten anywhere.

I have the following metatags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="I'm going to see Speaker name" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is the description of the speaker" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/Speakers.aspx?speaker=35" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/test.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="315">
```

After running this URL through the Facebook debug tool, I was given the following error message:
Object at URL 'http://example.com/Speakers.aspx?speaker=35' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:image:url' of type 'url' was not provided.

According to Open Graph protocol (http://ogp.me/#structured), the og:image & og:image:url are identical, but I tried to add it anyways:

```
<meta property="og:image:url" content="http://example.com/RGDDT/images/test.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
```

However the first 7 images on the page are still being scraped instead of the one I want to use.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the [best article on which metatags you need](http://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123). Facebook requires you to have an id, in order to use even a Like button now a days. I don't see those metatags in your snippet. Try adding:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1111111111111111" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="2222222222" />
```

The first is your app_id number, it seems you need to turn even your blog into an app to make Facebook happy. The second is your personal id number, you can also use your Fan Page if you have one. Including these things seems to make Facebook happy and I think you get Analytics for your troubles.

Comment: Thanks Muskie - The page I want to share is not a Facebook app so I don't see how this is relevant. The client doesn't even have a Facebook fan page associated with this website (not a blog). Also I'm not using a 'like' button. I'm using a 'Share' button via AddThis

Comment: All blogs are apps according to Facebook now, if you use the Facebook WordPress Plugin you must become an app. If you use Disqus plugin you must become an app. AddThis must be the app, they are getting the analytics not you.

Comment: The site is not built on Wordpress. It is not a blog. It is a website. I also am not using a Disqus plugin.

Comment: I don't think you understand Facebook's definition of an app. Everything that accesses the OpenGraph API in any meaningful way whether from a mobile device or from the web, Facebook seems to want to call an app and have it/them register. If you want the fanciest like/share button you need to register you app. Doesn't matter if you're a blog or an ecommerce website, you want the fanciest Facebook geewhiz features you need the magic id number.

Comment: Well as you can see I ended up resolving my problem. My sharing works as expected now without registering an app or providing an app ID in my metadata.

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally solved this problem.

**Problem #1**: I was using 'permanent' URLs (/getmedia/3c87abee-1cd0-4ca3-a07d-b7d8fde8ec4b/irma1.jpg.aspx?width=437&height=434&ext=.jpg) instead of 'direct' URLs (/RGDDT/media/RGDDT/Speakers/facebook-share/irma-boom.jpg?width=600&height=315&ext=.jpg). This was a setting I was able to configure in Kentico (the CMS we have used to build this site)

**Problem #2**: I was getting the results I wanted in the Facebook debug tool, but they were being cached when I tried to share from the live site. Thanks to [this article](http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/) I was able to solve that problem by adding '&v=1' (or '?v=1' if you don't already have a query string at the end of your URL), so Facebook considered this a new page request and didn't cache the description I had hardcoded in as of this morning.

Comment: Years later... how are you cramming the OG tags into the page in Kentico? Are you doing it in a generic way that I could reproduce so that most pages end up with nice links if someone tries to drop them into Facebook (or LinkedIn)?

Comment: I used a HEAD webpart